# Hyperledger Fabric: Unable to Update Certificate Attributes in Node SDK

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, x509certificate

I'm making a block chain application for which I'm using **Hyperledger Fabric Node SDK**. When a user **signs up** then the user's certificate is added to the wallet as an identity. Now the attributes that I'm storing in a user's certificate are the **email and password**.
Also, the user's password is not stored anywhere else, but only in the certificate.
Now, I also need to update the user's password.

Searching on the internet, I got to know that the attributes in the certificate can be updated using the **identityService's update function** provided in Node and you don't have to re-enroll a user if you're using the identityService's update function.
The issue is that I tried it and the response showed the updated password.
But then when I checked the certificate, **the old password was still there** i.e. it had not been updated.
I'm using the **fabric-ca-client** package for the FabricCAServices and the **x509** package for the x509 certificates.

The code with which I am enrolling and registering the user is as follows:

```
let ccp = await getCCP(orgName);
const caURL = await getCaUrl(orgName, ccp)
const ca = new FabricCAServices(caURL);
    
const walletPath = await getWalletPath(orgName);
const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
logger.info(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

const userIdentity = await wallet.get(email); //getting user from the wallet
if (userIdentity) //if found so user is already registered
{
    return "User Already Exists";
}
    
//else user does not exist so checking if admin exists
let adminIdentity = await wallet.get('admin'); //getting admin from wallet
if (!adminIdentity) { //if not found so admin does not exist
    logger.debug('An identity for the admin user "admin" does not exist in the wallet');
    await enrollAdmin(orgName, ccp); //enrolling the admin
    adminIdentity = await wallet.get('admin');
    logger.debug("Admin Enrolled Successfully");
}

//now admin exists, so making a user object for authenticating with the CA(i.e. admin)
const provider = wallet.getProviderRegistry().getProvider(adminIdentity.type);
const adminUser = await provider.getUserContext(adminIdentity, 'admin');
let secret;
try {
    //registering the user, enrolling the user, and importing the new identity into the wallet.
    secret = await ca.register({ affiliation: 'org1.department1', enrollmentID: email, role: 'client', attrs: [{name: 'userType', value: userType, ecert: true},{name: 'password', value: password, ecert: true}]}, adminUser);
} catch (error) {
    return error.message;
}

const enrollment = await ca.enroll({ enrollmentID: email, enrollmentSecret: secret, attr_reqs: [{  name: 'userType', optional: false }, {  name: 'password', optional: false }] });

let x509Identity;
if (orgName == "Org1") {
    x509Identity = {
        credentials: {
            certificate: enrollment.certificate,
            privateKey: enrollment.key.toBytes(),
        },
        mspId: 'Org1MSP',
        type: 'X.509',
    };
} else if (orgName == "Org2") {
    x509Identity = {
        credentials: {
            certificate: enrollment.certificate,
            privateKey: enrollment.key.toBytes(),
        },
        mspId: 'Org2MSP',
        type: 'X.509',
    };
}
await wallet.put(email, x509Identity); //adding user to wallet
return "Registered!";
```

And the code with which I check the attributes stored in the password is:

```
//Getting wallet path for orgName...
const walletPath = await getWalletPath(orgName);
const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
logger.info(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

//getting this user from the wallet
const userIdentity = await wallet.get(email);
if (userIdentity) { //if found i.e. user is registered
    //parsing certificate to get password
    var issuer = x509.parseCert(userIdentity.credentials.certificate);
    var jsn = issuer.extensions['1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1'];
    jsn = jsn.substring(2);
    jsn = (JSON.parse(jsn));
    //here jsn.attrs.password has the password
}
```

And the code that I'm using to update the certificate attributes is:

```
let ccp = await getCCP(orgName);
const caURL = await getCaUrl(orgName, ccp);
const ca = new FabricCAServices(caURL);

//Getting wallet path for orgName...
const walletPath = await getWalletPath(orgName);
const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
logger.info(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

const userIdentity = await wallet.get(email); //getting this user from the wallet
if (userIdentity) { //if found i.e. user is registered

    //Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node
    const gateway = new Gateway();
    await gateway.connect(ccp, { wallet, identity: email, discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });

    const identityService = ca.newIdentityService();

    let adminIdentity = await wallet.get('admin'); //getting admin from wallet
    //now making a user object of the admin
    const provider = wallet.getProviderRegistry().getProvider(adminIdentity.type);
    const adminUser = await provider.getUserContext(adminIdentity, 'admin');

    var theIdentityRequest = { enrollmentID: email, affiliation: 'org1.department1', attrs: [ {name: 'userType', value: 'Student', ecert: true},{name: 'password', value: newPassword, ecert: true} ] };

    logger.warn("The Request: ", theIdentityRequest);

    let response = await identityService.update(email, theIdentityRequest, adminUser);
                
    logger.warn("userIdenity attributes: ",response.result.attrs);

    await gateway.disconnect();
}
```

I want to know why the certificate still has the old password and how to update the password in the certificate.
And I also want to know that does the identityService update the attributes in the x509 certificate or is reenrolling the user necessary for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix it by doing `reenroll` as you said.

The `update` command of `IdentityService` is to update the identity of `registered` user in CA.
Since this is not the process of updating the certificate, the only way to obtain a certificate containing the newly modified `Attr` is to obtain a **new certificate** (the certificate is the X.509 standard).

---

Why does the attr change require a new certificate?

- Fabric generally uses the X.509 certificate standard method.(when not using idemix)
- Actually not only Fabric, almost all certificates on the web follow the standard.
- In Fabric, the `Attr` is existed in `extensions` in the X509(v3) certificate and has the following format.

```yaml
X509v3 extensions:
    ...
    1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1:
        {"attrs":{"hf.Affiliation":"org1.department1","hf.EnrollmentID":"appUser5","hf.Type":"client","userType":"userType"}}
    ...
```

- In other words, when `Attr` is modified, `extensions` are modified.
- In X.509(v3), `extenstions` are also included in the certificate integrity verification process.
- The integrity verification process is implemented based on `PKI` and `Hash`, and is provided in the form of attaching the `signature` signed by the CA to the hashed data (including extensions) to the certificate.
- That is, if `extensions` are modified, the `signature` in the certificate must be modified, which means that a **new certificate must be issued**.

---

Come back to Fabric,

- The `reenroll` command is an act of `newly issuing` enrolled user data based on the `registered user`.
- After `updating`, a new certificate is issued through the `reenroll` command to obtain a certificate that includes `new Attrs` in the corresponding certificate.

The following example code has been tested and works. See this.

```js
// registerUser, enrollUser, updateUser, reEnrollUser

/*
 * Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

'use strict';

const { Wallets } = require('fabric-network');
const FabricCAServices = require('fabric-ca-client');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

async function main() {
    try {
        // 0. given, already enrolled 'admin'
        const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'test-network', 'organizations', 'peerOrganizations', 'org1.example.com', 'connection-org1.json');
        const ccp = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(ccpPath, 'utf8'));
        const caURL = ccp.certificateAuthorities['ca.org1.example.com'].url;
        const ca = new FabricCAServices(caURL);
        const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
        const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
        const provider = wallet.getProviderRegistry().getProvider('X.509');
        
        // 1. register testUser
        const adminIdentity = await wallet.get('admin');
        const appUser = 'testUser';
        const adminUser = await provider.getUserContext(adminIdentity, 'admin');
        const secret = await ca.register({
                affiliation: 'org1.department2',
                attrs: [{name: 'userType', value: 'userType', ecert: true}],
                enrollmentID: appUser,
                role: 'client'
        }, adminUser);

        // 2. enroll testUser
        const enrollment = await ca.enroll({
                enrollmentID: appUser,
                enrollmentSecret: secret
        });
        const x509Identity = {
                credentials: {
                        certificate: enrollment.certificate,
                        privateKey: enrollment.key.toBytes(),
                },
                mspId: 'Org1MSP',
                type: 'X.509',
        };
        await wallet.put(appUser, x509Identity);

        // 3. update testUser's Identity in Fabric-CA
        const appUserIdentity = await wallet.get(appUser);
        const newAppUser = await provider.getUserContext(appUserIdentity, appUser);
        const identityService = ca.newIdentityService();
        var theIdentityRequest = { enrollmentID: appUser, affiliation: 'org1.department1', attrs: [ {name: 'userType', value: 'Student', ecert: true} ] };
        let response = await identityService.update(appUser, theIdentityRequest, adminUser);
        console.log("userIdenity attributes: ", response.result.attrs);

        // 4. reenroll testUser
        const newEnrollment = await ca.reenroll(newAppUser);
        const newX509Identity = {
                credentials: {
                        certificate: newEnrollment.certificate,
                        privateKey: newEnrollment.key.toBytes(),
                },
                mspId: 'Org1MSP',
                type: 'X.509',
        };
        await wallet.put(`new_${appUser}`, newX509Identity);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to register user "appUser": ${error}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}
```

```sh
ls wallet
testUser.id  new_testUser.id
```

The result of docode the issued certificate
(`hf.Affiliation` and `userType` are updated)

```
// attrs in 'enroll' Certificate's extensions
{"attrs": "hf.Affiliation":"org1.department2","hf.EnrollmentID":"testUser","hf.Type":"client","userType":"userType"}}

// attrs in 'reenroll' Certificate's extensions
{"attrs":{"hf.Affiliation":"org1.department1","hf.EnrollmentID":"testUser","hf.Type":"client","userType":"Student"}}
```

---

[P.S] Looking at the `Version` indicated in the client's identity, it seems that there may be a way to upgrade the existing one, but I have not checked or tried it.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you so much!